# Call appropriate constructor depending on value_type : integer or float

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I have a function which fills a container with random values between min and max using uniform distribution.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

template<typename TContainer>
void uniform_random(TContainer& container, 
const typename TContainer::value_type min, 
const typename TContainer::value_type max) {
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());

    // Below line does not work with integers container
    std::uniform_real_distribution<typename TContainer::value_type> distribution(min, max);

    auto lambda_norm_dist = [&](){ return distribution(gen); };
    std::generate(container.begin(), container.end(), lambda_norm_dist);
}

int main() {
    std::vector<float> a(10);
    uniform_random(a,0,10);
    for (auto el : a) { std::cout << el << " "; }
}
```

Replacing `std::vector<float>` with `std::vector<int>` does not work since I would have to use `std::uniform_int_distribution` instead.
Is there a simple and elegant way to pick the right constructor depending on the value_type parameter ?

I was trying so far to use `std::numeric_limits<typename TContainer::value_type>::is_integer` without success.

Comment: Use proper source highlighting (backticks). If you enclose code in simple emphasis (asterisk), angled brackets don't show up. (Fixed.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Write a meta-function `select_distribution` which allows you to write this:

```
using value_type = typename TContainer::value_type;

using distribution_type = typename select_distribution<value_type>::type;

distribution_type  distribution(min, max);
```

where `select_distribution` is defined as:

```
template<typename T, bool = std::is_floating_point<T>::value>   
struct select_distribution
{
  using type = std::uniform_real_distribution<T>;
};

template<typename T>   
struct select_distribution<T, false>
{
  using type = std::uniform_int_distribution<T>;
};
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: `template <typename T> using select_distribution = std::conditional_t<std::is_float<T>::value, std::uniform_real_distribution<T>, std::uniform_int_distribution<T>>;`

Comment: @SebastianRedl: I think that wont work, because both branch needs to compile, but they're mutually exclusive!

Comment: `std::uniform_real_distribution<int>` compiles as long as you don't need the definition of the class, unless the standard library does very tricky and non-standard things to prevent this.

Comment: @SebastianRedl: If that is so, then that would be best. I thought of using that, but rejected it thinking `std::conditional` is eagerly evaluated.

Comment: Thank you ! Voted for this one I find it personaly more intuitive.

Answer (score 7):

In C++14 (or C++11 with a minor change) you can create a `uniform_distribution` type alias in this way:

```
template <typename ValueType>
using uniform_distribution = std::conditional_t<
    std::is_floating_point<ValueType>::value,
    std::uniform_real_distribution<ValueType>,
    std::uniform_int_distribution<ValueType>
 >;
```

Usage:

```
uniform_distribution<typename TContainer::value_type> distribution(min, max);
```

Answer (score 4):

One solution is to use a type trait helper and `std::enable_if`:

```
template<class T, class Enable = void>
struct uniform_distribution_helper {};

template<class T>
struct uniform_distribution_helper<T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_floating_point<T>::value >::type> {
    using type = std::uniform_real_distribution<T>;
};

template<class T>
struct uniform_distribution_helper<T, typename  std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value >::type> {
    using type = std::uniform_int_distribution<T>;
};
```

Then in your function:

```
using uniform_distribution = typename uniform_distribution_helper<typename TContainer::value_type>::type;
// Below line does not work with integers container
uniform_distribution distribution(min, max);
```

Comment: Thank you for enlightment ! I have tried using `std::enable_if` without success.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a traits class. For example:

```
template <typename NumType>
struct ValueTraits;

template <>
struct ValueTraits<int>
{        
    using UniformDistributionType = std::uniform_int_distribution<int>;
};
```

You can do it based on types (and then you might need quite a few Traits classes), or based on a bool value (the result of is_integer), and then you'll need to template your `using`.

And then in your class:

```
// In the class scope:
typedef TContainer::value_type value_type;

// And in your constructor:
typename ValueTraits<value_type>::UniformDistributionType distribution(min, max);
```