# Different template behavior for integer and real types

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

How to create template with different behavior for different types (some pseudo language), for example:

```
template <typename T>
T GetRand(T param)
{
    if (T is of any real type) {
        // use uniform_real_distribution
    }

    if (T is of any integer type) {
        // use uniform_int_distribution
    }

    if (T is of any other type) {
        // do nothing
    }
}
```

How to write those `if T is of xxx type`?

If it makes sense, I use C++11.

Comment: You can use [`type_traits`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/type_traits)

Comment: Tag dispatching could be useful.

Comment: Take a look at [Call appropriate constructor depending on value_type : integer or float](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29747259/call-appropriate-constructor-depending-on-value-type-integer-or-float)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use SFINAE on every overload of `GetRand`, but at some point it becomes a lot simpler to use tag-dispatch. We're going to pick a unique type for each of our potential overloads ("`T` is of any real type", "`T` is of any integer type", "other") and construct the correct one as a second argument to a helper function.

First, we have to pick the correct tag:

```
struct integral_tag{};
struct floating_tag{};
struct other_tag{};

template <typename T>
struct get_tag 
: std::conditional<
    std::is_integral<T>::value,
    integral_tag,
    typename std::conditional<
        std::is_floating_point<T>::value,
        floating_tag,
        other_tag>::type
    > 
{ };

template <typename T>
using get_tag_t = typename get_tag<T>::type;
```

Then, we use that type trait to do our forwarding:

```
template <typename T>
T GetRand(T param) {
    return GetRand(param, get_tag_t<T>{} );
}
```

And then just write those overloads:

```
template <typename T>
T GetRand(T param, integral_tag ) { ... };

template <typename T>
T GetRand(T param, floating_tag ) { ... };

template <typename T>
T GetRand(T param, other_tag ) { ... };
```

Personally, I think that's easier to read.

Comment: Great solution, I like it :)

Answer (score 5):

The problem with using if statements like that is that the bodies need to be compilable for any `T`, regardless of whether that code would ever actually be run.

You would be better off using specialization or similar to specify your behaviour. An example which uses SFINAE and the `type_traits` header:

```
template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral<T>::value>* = nullptr>
T GetRand(T param)
{
   cout << "int version\n"; 
}

template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point<T>::value>* = nullptr>
T GetRand(T param)
{
   cout << "float version\n"; 
}

template <typename T,
          std::enable_if_t<!(std::is_floating_point<T>::value ||
                             std::is_integral<T>::value)>* = nullptr>
T GetRand(T param)
{
   cout << "other version\n"; 
}
```

Comment: Then you can just use `typename std::enable_if<...>::type*`